# Can I charge my laptop using an External laptop charger?

Tags: battery, charging

How can I charge my Gateway laptop without using a computer? My battery cannot be charged onn the computer because the mother board is damaged.

Comment: How sure are you that the battery can't be charged due to a motherboard defect, and its not simply the battery that can't be charged because it was overcharged?

Comment: Find wiring diagram for battery + voltage/current information. Calibrate battery charger appropriately. Connect. Monitor for heat build up.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:

It depends, but probably it won't (that is, for the majority of laptops, that won't be possible). The reason behind this is that the input voltage of laptops is usually something between 15 and 20 V (for instance, mine is at 19V). The output of external battery chargers (as ones used for mobile phones, etc.) however is usually at 5V. You have to understand that its theoretically possible to charge at lower voltages - it will only take longer. But the charging modules inside the machines prevent that for circuitry reasons by accepting voltages only at a specific threshold.

Case in point, I once searched for a moderately sized external charger to charge my tablet. That has actually an input of 15V, but it also seems to accept 12V. So luckily I was able to purchase a battery pack that has a switch to either output 5V or 12V.

Long story short, as long as your laptop does not allow lower input voltages or you do not find an external charger that has such a high output, you are out of luck. In any case, to completely charge your laptop, the charger would need quite a huge battery itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible but not simple, you need make some changes to your power supply and make special output as your battery needs.

As I know on power supply (24pin) we have +12,-12,+5,-5 And oranges +3.3

Use black color (ground=0) and yellow cable for 12v .

So you can use -12 (blue) & +3  for making 15v outpost And something like this.

Comment: For 19v you can use -12v & +12v , But you need reduce voltage with reduce voltage circuits.